# Why are all my Homebrew packages suddenly "unlinked"; how do I fix that?

Tags: homebrew

Recently `brew doctor` or `brew upgrade --all` (I'm not sure which, I run them in a script) reported the following:

```
Homebrew from 5371359 to e3fe270.
Updated 3 taps (caskroom/cask, homebrew/boneyard, homebrew/core).
Error: Could not symlink bin/dvipdf
Target /usr/local/bin/dvipdf
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/dvipdf'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite ghostscript

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run ghostscript
Error: Could not symlink bin/easy_install
Target /usr/local/bin/easy_install
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/easy_install'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite python

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run python:
```

I followed these instructions by running:

```
 brew link --overwrite python
 brew link --overwrite ghostscript
```

But now whenever I run `brew doctor`  get:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
    # A list of EVERYTHING listed by brew list
```

That is: `brew doctor` now shows *everything I have installed* — everything listed by `brew list` — as unlinked!

What's going on here? Why is everything I've ever installed using Homebrew suddenly unlinked? How did they get that way? What can I (safely) do to fix my Homebrew installation (aside from manually running `brew link --overwrite ...` individually on every thing I've installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `brew update` (twice if necessary) should sort this out.

If not, `brew unlink $(brew list); brew link $(brew list)` will.

Comment: Any idea why this has suddenly started happening?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Bug in migration code. (Both Mike and I are Homebrew maintainers).

Comment: I get a lot of `xxxx is keg-only and must be linked with --force`. What should i do about those? I also get `Refusing to link: openssl`; what's best practice there?

Comment: You should ignore those warnings.

Comment: Sorry about the breakage by the way.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Just remembered SO's weird notification system means you probably weren't notified about my comment above. Mentioning you just in case.

Comment: @4ae1e1: No worries. Thanks for the quick replies!